# Need to prevent merge of branch into HEAD

Tags: git, version-control

I have seen variations of this question but haven't found an answer. I am trying to find a way to prevent merging of a specific local branch (dev) into whatever the current HEAD branch is.

So, dev(HEAD) can be merged into. However, dev cannot merge into branch-x(HEAD). I am open to different recommendations. Please ask any questions of me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot stop other people from doing anything they want in their own private Git repositories.  What *would* you like to stop?  Certain cases of push on some server(s)?  Various accidental merges in your own private repository?

Comment: This would be a local setting to prevent accidental merging of one branch into another.

Comment: There's no `pre-merge` Git hook.  You can cobble something together using `pre-commit` and/or `prepare-commit-msg`, but I wouldn't: better to make your `git` front end a shell alias or script that checks whether you're running `git merge` and if so, checks the arguments.  Or train yourself to run a different command, `gmerge` or some such, and make that the alias/script that checks.